# Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem - question

Tags: logic, incompleteness

Could someone correct me on the below logic.

If a statement cannot be proved then I cannot find a contradiction to said statement. *If I cannot find a contradiction to said statement then that statement must be true*. Hence all unprovable statements must be true.

Can we not take the italic text as a definition of what it means for something to be true? Or in other words, would it makes sense for something without contradictions to be false? Are there examples of such constructs?

Comment: *"If a statement cannot be proved then I cannot find a contradiction to said statement"* What do you mean? You can't prove $\forall x\ x = 1$, and $2$ is a contradiction to it.

Comment: The problem is that you can easily find two incompatible statements that cannot be disproved from the same theory (say, CH and its negation in ZFC). By your definition, they would be both true and create a contradiction.

Comment: I cannot think of a single way to interpret "If I cannot find a contradiction to said statement then that statement must be true" so that it is true. (There is a sense in which *a certain type of* statement is "true if not falsifiable," namely the [$\Pi^0_1$ statements](), but this is a very limited phenomenon.)

Comment: hi Andy; maybe a very basic toy example will help. consider a mathematical "theory" that just consists of a single axiom $A$. axiom $A$ says "there exist at least two objects". now, consider the statement $B$, which says "there exist at least three objects". is $B$ provable or disprovable from $A$? can you find a contradiction to statement $B$ from axiom $A$? the answer is no, but does that mean that statement $B$ actually follows from axiom $A$?

Comment: (Whoops, missed the link in my previous comment: [here it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy).)

Comment: @Atticus The statement that you pose 'there exist at least three objects' has nothing to do with axiom A. I suppose when we lay out axioms it is implied as to what sort of objects we can talk about. In your example, the only statements we can talk about are 'There exists one object' (false), 'There exists 6 objects' (true).

The words 'at least' whilst subtle in the english language is nonsensical with respect to the axiom.

Comment: @JackM here by statement I should have maybe used a different word such as 'theorem'

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone correct me on the below logic.

> If a statement cannot be proved then I cannot find a contradiction to said statement. *If I cannot find a contradiction to said statement then that statement must be true*. Hence all unprovable statements must be true.

The *logic* of your argument is flawless: it's a valid categorical syllogism.

The *assumptions* of your argument, however, are flawed:

> If a statement cannot be proved then I cannot find a contradiction to said statement.

False.  Unless you're working with an inconsistent set of assumptions, you cannot prove $0 \neq 0$. But you can find (and prove) its contradictory statement $0 = 0$

> *If I cannot find a contradiction to said statement then that statement must be true*.

Also False. By Godel's Incompleteness Theorem, if you're working in a 'strong enough' yet consistent system, there will be statements that are true but that cannot be proven ... most notably the system's Godel sentence that effectively says 'The Godel sentence for this system cannot be proven in this very system'. And note that its contradictory statement 'The Godel sentence for this system can be proven in this very system' is false, and cannot be proven either. So you cannot prove the contradictory of the negation of the Godel sentence ... but it is not a true statement.